# Half screen appears to have film on it. Acer C7 Chromebook running 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, intel, display

Right side of the screen is not processing colors properly. Does not show up in white space but when colors deep colors occur the right side is lighter and it seems to be a bit blurry as well.

I toggled back to chrome but it doesn't seem to be an issue there. I from 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04 and all of them have the exact problem. I tried re-installing the intel drivers in all three but nothing changed. I also hooked it up to a HDTV which worked fine.

I looked into calibrating the colors of the monitor but couldn't quite figure it out. Does anyone know of a good color profile online with good instructions?

I believe the C7 runs the Intel HD graphics 4000, which I have seen some problems occurring.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool that can get a screen capture, e.g. [the gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), and move the resulting image to another computer. If it looks ok, then colors are being sent to the framebuffer fine, and its your screen that has gone bad. The fact that it works fine on your HDTV strongly suggests this is a problem with your LCD panel.

It is not a problem with color calibration, that would affect the entire screen, not half of it.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. I went back to chrome os and checked more closely and there is the exact same problem. Will be exchanging tomorrow.